# Unable to create/start a project in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have installed ionic successfully version = 1.7.16. I just started to create and start a sample blank project using command

```
ionic start todo blank
```

It gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\kevin>ionic start todo blank

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:17:20
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\unzip\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)

Cannot find module 'internal/fs' (CLI v1.7.16)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS:
Node Version: v7.2.1
```

Attached the screen shot of the error for your reference : [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI890.png).

Browsed for solution online but couldn't find one to resolve the issue.

Comment: Check out this forum: [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9377) a lot of people with similar issue, with different solutions.

Comment: Hi I have installed latest version of node.js 7.2.1 and npm comes along with it @ 4.0.3.
Workarounds done but failed to resolve issue
**1.)**   Removed node_modules folder from local folder        -- error not resolved
**2.)**   Uninstalled node js and re-installed                 -- error not resolved
**3.)**   Installed earlier ver of:npm -g install npm@3.10.10  -- error not resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried all the possible ways to eliminate the error but all my attempts gone in vain.

To eliminate the above error I have installed latest version of ionic i.e., 2.1.17 Where as earlier it was 1.7.16 which I have purposefully installed.

Answer (score 0):

ive removed all the node.js package on my OS

## apt-get purge node.js

and manually remove/clear

/home/user*/(.npm,.ionic), /root/(.npm,.ionic), /usr/lib/node_modules

manual removal of the remainder helped and update your OS and new install node.js and ionic

cu